# How to list all files of a particular folder in gitlab branch using java

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am writing one utility in Java to access all JSON files from a particular folder say "XYZ" of my gitlab repository's branch. I have private access token of my gitlab profile, username & password with me.

I tried to use maven dependency as:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gitlab</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-gitlab-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
     </dependency>
```

In my code, I imported things as:

```
 import org.gitlab.api.GitlabAPI;
 import org.gitlab.api.models.GitlabSession;
```

Further, I don't know how I can list down JSON files of particular folder present in a branch of my repository. I tried to get current Gitlab session something like:

```
    GitlabSession gitLabApi = GitlabAPI.connect(GITLAB_URL, Username, password);
String privateGitlabToken = gitLabApi.getPrivateToken();
```